# Is the definition of Investment variable in Economics?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, investment, productivity, producer-theory

I studied that Investment is the expenditure incurred on the procurement of such goods that would help us in production of goods and services.
And mainly consists of Fixed and Inventory Investment

Is this the only definition of investment in economics ?
Or definition of investment changes when we talk about different concepts ?